# AS3 Why am I using get / getter the wrong way?

Tags: actionscript-3, get, encapsulation, getter

something is wrong with my encapsulation, but i dont know what it is:

I got a document class named Main bound to the stage:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

  public class Main extends MovieClip
  {
    var chapter1:Chapter1;

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        chapter1 = new Chapter1;
        addChild(chapter1);
    }   
  }
}
```

a Chapter1 class bound to a MovieClip:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

 public class Chapter1 extends MovieClip {

    public var numberOfFrames:uint;

    public function Chapter1() 
    {
        numberOfFrames = 3;

        //constructor
        trace("Chapter 1 constructed");
        Transition.moveFromTo();

    }

    public static function get getNumberOfFrames():uint
    {
        return numberOfFrames;
    }

 }
}
```

and a class called Transition that i like to use as a simple utility:

```
package  {

 public class Transition {

    public var gotNumber:uint;

    public function Transition() {
        trace(Chapter1.getNumberOfFrames);
    }

    static public function moveFromTo()
    {
        /* in the end id like to use this as a utility working with 
                     NumberOfFrames from a parent Chapter instance.*/
    }

 }
}
```

I get an error message telling me: "1120: Access of undefined property numberOfFrames." so the getter function itself seems not to be allowed to use numberOfFrames. But I dont see why, for all examples I found (although working just with two classes and no binding) make the getter return a var just like that. Do I miss something there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getNumberOfFrames()` function is a static function but it's trying to access `numberOfFrames` which is an instance member variable. You have to create an instance of `Chapter1` so that an instance of `numberOfFrames` would be allocated - `numberOfFrames` doesn't exist outside of a specific instance of `Chapter1`.

Furthermore, the `getNumberOfFrames()` function itself needs access to a `Chapter1` instance to retrieve its `numberOfFrames` member - a static function exists outside of each instance.

One possible solution is to assign a `Chapter1` instance to your `Transition` class so that inside you can use that instance when you try to get the number of frames.

If you can have multiple `Chapter1` and multiple `Transition` objects in your program, I'd suggest removing the `static` keywords from your classes since all static functions will need an instance to work with.

Comment: thanx for the info. the static keyword is easy to remove. but i thought i was creating an instance of Chapter1 named "chapter1" inside the Main constructor via the new keyword and the addChild() method. seems i am wrong there too. i guess i didnt really understand creating instances (darn)...

Comment: @gauguerilla When you're creating a movieclip, you are, indeed, creating an instance. That instance, however, is not directly accessible by your code. You must call `getChildByName()` against the parent movie clip to get a reference to that instance. Once you have it, you can then access its public properties / methods.

Comment: @gauguerilla If you're creating your movie clip in code using `new` then you can also just store a reference to that movie clip in a member variable of one of your classes (where it makes sense) and then access it later. In this case you can avoid using `getChildByName()` which is somewhat expensive.

Comment: thx. again. i figured it out with your and Lee Burrows help. I missunderstood the whole concept of "static" and now finally figured out what it was. <3

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the getter as a static. Just remove the static keyword:

```
public function get getNumberOfFrames():uint
{
    return numberOfFrames;
}
```

Defining something as static means that every instance of the class uses a single instance of the property or method - im guessing that's not what you want (presumably each Chapter you create may have different values for numberOfFrames?)

Comment: exactly! i want to have different chapters with different numberOfFrames but use all the same method from the Transition class. thanks for the fast answer. seems i have a lot more the wrong way (instanciating chapter1, see xxbbccs comment). removing the static keyword just produces another error: "1119: Access of possibly undefined property getNumberOfFrames through a reference with static type Class."